# Undo/redo drupal console generate:plugin:block?

Tags: console

I ran drupal console generate:plugin:block and made a mistake.  I'd like to run it again, but I get this error:

```
 'block' entity with ID 'my_block' already exists.
```

I've removed the source file that the command created, but this error still persists.  I'm guessing the block was added to the site's actual configuration.  How can I undo/overwrite it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the answer myself:

```
 drupal config:delete active block.block.my_block
```

(For my specific case)  Good luck finding the configuration name.  There's no listing from the console.  I had to export the whole damn thing to a directory and grep for it.

Comment: `drupal debug:plugin | grep my_block` is useful for future reference

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give that a try